# Is there any way to see the users who have commit access to a public GitHub repo?

Tags: github

On GitHub I can see the contributors who have submitted pull requests. However, is there any way to see the full list of collaborators who have commit access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/) and get the list of collaborator for a given repostory

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators
```

Note that it depends of your credentials when you are doing this query:

> - When authenticating as an organization owner of an organization-owned repository, all organization owners are included in the list of collaborators.
> - Otherwise, only users with access to the repository are returned in the collaborators list.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Typing a URL like that into my address bar worked. https://api.github.com/repos/meskyanichi/backup/collaborators